# How to serve files locally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, path

In my Angular directive, I'm trying to get the path to another folder outside of the project, that contains a bunch of files. The idea is to join that path with the list of files existent and draw them using the `omnivore`library (It is not important here, but I'll leave the code for some context):

```
  var folderPath = "../../../traceMySteps-backend/MyTracks/ProcessedTracks/";

 return {

        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attr, $http) {

              for (var i = 0; i < jsonRes.length; i += 1) {
                console.log(folderPath + jsonRes[i])
                omnivore.gpx(folderPath + jsonRes[i]).addTo(trackmaps[trackmapCount]);
              }

...
```

The problem is that Angular thinks the folder is on the localhost: `http://localhost:8000/traceMySteps-backend/MyTracks/ProcessedTracks/2016-05-04-‌​part1.gpx` when the folder is outside this Angular project

The folder structure is:

```
Backend_folder/MyTracks/ProcessedTracks/
Angular_Project/app/js/directives/file
```

`Backend_folder` and `Angular_Project` are at the same level (both inside one folder). And in that `file` is where that directive code is. I need to access `ProcessedTracks/` from it. Is there any way? This relative path does not work and I've also tried the absolute path, but the error is the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I serve static files through Node.js locally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145451/how-do-i-serve-static-files-through-node-js-locally)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the client (browser) doesn't have access to directory structure as this is a security risk. I think you can do this by installing some 3rd party tools on the server or exposing your files via a web service.