# Failed to load static resources

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created `app.js` file like below:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public/styles'));
app.use(express.static('public/views'));
app.use(express.static('public/images'));

module.exports = app;
```

When I add `app.listen(8000);` and I start my app by `node app.js` everything looks good.
But I wanted to have server in different file so I created `server.js` file like below:

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('../app');

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

When I started server by `node server.js` I am getting error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `404 (Not Found)`

My path:

```
-server
 -bin
  -server.js
 -public
  -images
  -styles
   -style.css
  -views
   -index.html
 -app.js
```

How it should looks like? What's wrong? Please explain me precisely.

I also tried to use it in `server.js` but didn't work:

```
const app = require('../app');

app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: And where is `server.js` in this tree?

Comment: You can refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145451/how-do-i-serve-static-files-through-node-js-locally

Comment: Why do you use `http.createServer(app).listen(8000);` instead of just `app.listen(8000)`? Also, where is `server.js` located?

Comment: I updated post. Server.js file is in bin folder. I tried use app.listen(8000) but still the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Are you referring your css like http://localhost:8000/public/styles/somesytle,css? or http://localhost:8000/styles/somesytle,css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change path of your statics. It should be relative to your `server.js`

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('../public/styles'));
app.use(express.static('../public/views'));
app.use(express.static('../public/images'));

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: It was brilliant suggestion! I added it ../ before public and now it works great, thanks a lot. It works with app.listen(8000); in server.js file of course.